# How to get a list of the name of every open window?

Tags: python, win32gui, pywinauto

How do I get a list of the name/text of all opened windows?

I tried pywinauto:

`pywinauto.findwindows.find_windows(title_re="*")`
but using `*` as a regex raises an error

I tried win32gui:
It has

`win32gui.GetWindowText(win32gui.GetForegroundWindow())`

But in its docs I couldn't find a getAllWindows or something that returns all names/texts of open hwnd handles:
http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/contents.html

Comment: Have a look at EnumWindows

Answer (score 33):

You can use [`win32gui.GetWindowText( hwnd )`](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32gui__GetWindowText_meth.html) along with [`win32gui.EnumWindows`](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32gui__EnumWindows_meth.html):

```
import win32gui

def winEnumHandler( hwnd, ctx ):
    if win32gui.IsWindowVisible( hwnd ):
        print ( hex( hwnd ), win32gui.GetWindowText( hwnd ) )

win32gui.EnumWindows( winEnumHandler, None )
```

---

Output:

```
0x20fa4 bet - [C:\Users\X\Desktop\] - [bet] - L:\stack\stack_enum_windows.py - IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.5
0x1932478 13. vnc 888
0x30c27b8 Telegram (55)
0x40aba MobaXterm
0x10a0a IntelliJIDEALicenseServer_windows_amd64.exe - Shortcut
...
```

Answer (score 21):

If you want using pywinauto, it's much easier:

```
from pywinauto import Desktop

windows = Desktop(backend="uia").windows()
print([w.window_text() for w in windows])
```

This should work even for WPF applications. Using `win32gui.EnumWindows` can't access texts for WPF or UWP applications. pywinauto uses `win32gui.EnumWindows` inside `Desktop(backend="win32")`. `backend="uia"` uses newer API from `UIAutomationCore.dll`.

More details about backends in pywinauto can be found in the [Getting Started Guide](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html).

Answer (score 11):

You can also utilize pyautogui,
by:

```
import pyautogui

for x in pyautogui.getAllWindows():  
    print(x.title)
```

Comment: I find this much faster than pywinauto. You can also do `pyautogui.getAllTitles()` to get a list of all open window titles

Comment: The `getAllWindows` and `getAllTitles` functions are no longer available.

Comment: Currently this seems a nice solution, but there are problems when using Linux and pipenv. https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui/issues/683