# How to take Screen shot in real-time(like video capture) on mac os?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, opencv3.0

I use opencv for automating games therefore i need to take screen shots of what is going on screen in real time. I use pywin32 for it while I am on windows.
**Is there a way to get similar effect on macos? or any other alternatives**

```
class WindowCapture:

# properties
w = 0
h = 0
hwnd = None
cropped_x = 0
cropped_y = 0
offset_x = 0
offset_y = 0

# constructor
def __init__(self, window_name):
    # find the handle for the window we want to capture
    self.hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, window_name)
    if not self.hwnd:
        raise Exception('Window not found: {}'.format(window_name))

    # get the window size
    window_rect = win32gui.GetWindowRect(self.hwnd)
    self.w = window_rect[2] - window_rect[0]
    self.h = window_rect[3] - window_rect[1]

    # account for the window border and titlebar and cut them off
    border_pixels = 8
    titlebar_pixels = 30
    self.w = self.w - (border_pixels * 2)
    self.h = self.h - titlebar_pixels - border_pixels
    self.cropped_x = border_pixels
    self.cropped_y = titlebar_pixels

    # set the cropped coordinates offset so we can translate screenshot
    # images into actual screen positions
    self.offset_x = window_rect[0] + self.cropped_x
    self.offset_y = window_rect[1] + self.cropped_y

def get_screenshot(self):

    # get the window image data
    wDC = win32gui.GetWindowDC(self.hwnd)
    dcObj = win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle(wDC)
    cDC = dcObj.CreateCompatibleDC()
    dataBitMap = win32ui.CreateBitmap()
    dataBitMap.CreateCompatibleBitmap(dcObj, self.w, self.h)
    cDC.SelectObject(dataBitMap)
    cDC.BitBlt((0, 0), (self.w, self.h), dcObj, (self.cropped_x, self.cropped_y), win32con.SRCCOPY)

    # convert the raw data into a format opencv can read
    #dataBitMap.SaveBitmapFile(cDC, 'debug.bmp')
    signedIntsArray = dataBitMap.GetBitmapBits(True)
    img = np.fromstring(signedIntsArray, dtype='uint8')
    img.shape = (self.h, self.w, 4)

    # free resources
    dcObj.DeleteDC()
    cDC.DeleteDC()
    win32gui.ReleaseDC(self.hwnd, wDC)
    win32gui.DeleteObject(dataBitMap.GetHandle())

    # drop the alpha channel, or cv.matchTemplate() will throw an error like:
    #   error: (-215:Assertion failed) (depth == CV_8U || depth == CV_32F) && type == _templ.type()
    #   && _img.dims() <= 2 in function 'cv::matchTemplate'
    img = img[...,:3]

    # make image C_CONTIGUOUS to avoid errors that look like:
    #   File ... in draw_rectangles
    #   TypeError: an integer is required (got type tuple)
    # see the discussion here:
    # https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/14866#issuecomment-580207109
    img = np.ascontiguousarray(img)

    return img

# find the name of the window you're interested in.
# once you have it, update window_capture()
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55547940/how-to-get-a-list-of-the-name-of-every-open-window
def list_window_names(self):
    def winEnumHandler(hwnd, ctx):
        if win32gui.IsWindowVisible(hwnd):
            print(hex(hwnd), win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd))
    win32gui.EnumWindows(winEnumHandler, None)

# translate a pixel position on a screenshot image to a pixel position on the screen.
# pos = (x, y)
# WARNING: if you move the window being captured after execution is started, this will
# return incorrect coordinates, because the window position is only calculated in
# the __init__ constructor.
def get_screen_position(self, pos):
    return (pos[0] + self.offset_x, pos[1] + self.offset_y)
```

I use above code for windows(found it on stackoverflow just copy/pasted it and edited it a little)

Comment: macOS has a built-in tool called *screencapture*. You could invoke that as a subprocess. There may be better ways

Comment: See https://pypi.org/project/PyAutoGUI/