# How can I speed up these if statements?

Tags: python, numpy, if-statement, multiprocessing

Currently, my code runs fine it's just running a bit slow for my use. I am using OpenCV to capture the screen and then checking those results using some if statements. I believe the current bottleneck is in the if statements.

```
pyautogui.PAUSE = 0.005

Location1 = range(90, 289)
Location2 = range(290, 400) # 394, 403f
Location3 = range(450, 630)# 551, 565
Location4 = range(640, 800) # 730, 695
Location5 = range(801, 1000)
empty = []

# Change the working directory to the folder this script is in.
# Doing this because I'll be putting the files from each video in their own folder on GitHub
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

# initialize the WindowCapture class
wincap = WindowCapture(None)
# initialize the Vision class
vision_limestone = Vision('Festivalnote.jpg')



keys = []
inputs = []

loop_time = time()
while 1:

    # get an updated image of the game
    screenshot = wincap.get_screenshot()

    #haystack_img = vision_limestone.apply_hsv_filter(screenshot)
    # display the processed image
    points = vision_limestone.find(screenshot, 0.5)#, 'rectangles')
    
    #cv.imshow('Matches', haystack_img)

    #length = len(keys)

    if points == empty:
        points = [(0, 0, 0)]
    
    if len(points) < 3:
        points.append((0, 0))
        points.append ((0, 0))

    first, sec, thd, *others = points
    #print(points)

    y_thresh = 175


    if first [0] in Location1 or sec[0] in Location1 or thd[0] in Location1:
        #print('d')
        pyautogui.keyDown("d")
        pyautogui.keyUp("d")
        #keys.append('d')
        #inputs.append('d')
        

    if first [0] in Location2 or sec[0] in Location2 or thd[0] in Location2:
        pyautogui.keyDown("f")
        pyautogui.keyUp("f")
        #print('f')
        #keys.append('f')
        #inputs.append("f")

    if first [0] in Location3 or sec[0] in Location3 or thd[0] in Location3:
        pyautogui.keyDown("j")
        pyautogui.keyUp("j")
        #print('j')
        #keys.append('j')
        #inputs.append('j')

    if first [0] in Location4 or sec[0] in Location4 or thd[0] in Location4:
        pyautogui.keyDown("k")
        pyautogui.keyUp("k")
        #print("k")
        #keys.append('k')
        #inputs.append('k')
    
    if first [0] in Location5 or sec[0] in Location5 or thd[0] in Location5:
        pyautogui.keyDown("l")
        pyautogui.keyUp("l")
        #print("l")
        #keys.append('l')
        #inputs.append('l')

    #if length == len(keys):
        #inputs.append(time() - loop_time)

    #print(inputs)
    # debug the loop rate
    print('FPS {}'.format(1 / (time() - loop_time)))
    loop_time = time()

    # press 'q' with the output window focused to exit.
    # waits 1 ms every loop to process key presses
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
```

I really have no idea if this even can be sped up as I am a newer coder however I looked at numpy and doing loops that way but I didn't see a way to do this using numpy (correct me if I'm wrong). I also looked at multiprocessing, however it's my understanding that I couldn't call back to the screenshot from within the threads and would thus have to take a screenshot for every thread which seems like it would be slower. please let me know of any ways you think I could speed this up. Full code.

```
def func():   
    import cv2
    import numpy as np
    import os
    from time import time
    import pyautogui
    import win32gui, win32ui, win32con


    class WindowCapture:

        # properties
        w = 0
        h = 0
        hwnd = None
        cropped_x = 800
        cropped_y = 950
        offset_x = 0
        offset_y = 0

        # constructor
        def __init__(self, window_name=None):
            # find the handle for the window we want to capture.
            # if no window name is given, capture the entire screen
            if window_name is None:
                self.hwnd = win32gui.GetDesktopWindow()
            else:
                self.hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, window_name)
                if not self.hwnd:
                    raise Exception('Window not found: {}'.format(window_name))

            # get the window size
            window_rect = win32gui.GetWindowRect(self.hwnd)
            self.w = 1000 #window_rect[2] - window_rect[0]
            self.h = 300 #window_rect[3] - window_rect[1]

            # account for the window border and titlebar and cut them off
            #border_pixels = 8
            #titlebar_pixels = 30
            #self.w = self.w - (border_pixels * 2)
            #self.h = self.h - titlebar_pixels - border_pixels
            #self.cropped_x = border_pixels
            #self.cropped_y = titlebar_pixels

            # set the cropped coordinates offset so we can translate screenshot
            # images into actual screen positions
            self.offset_x = window_rect[0] + self.cropped_x
            self.offset_y = window_rect[1] + self.cropped_y

        def get_screenshot(self):

            # get the window image data
            wDC = win32gui.GetWindowDC(self.hwnd)
            dcObj = win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle(wDC)
            cDC = dcObj.CreateCompatibleDC()
            dataBitMap = win32ui.CreateBitmap()
            dataBitMap.CreateCompatibleBitmap(dcObj, self.w, self.h)
            cDC.SelectObject(dataBitMap)
            cDC.BitBlt((0, 0), (self.w, self.h), dcObj, (self.cropped_x, self.cropped_y), win32con.SRCCOPY)

            # convert the raw data into a format opencv can read
            #dataBitMap.SaveBitmapFile(cDC, 'debug.bmp')
            signedIntsArray = dataBitMap.GetBitmapBits(True)
            img = np.fromstring(signedIntsArray, dtype='uint8')
            img.shape = (self.h, self.w, 4)

            # free resources
            dcObj.DeleteDC()
            cDC.DeleteDC()
            win32gui.ReleaseDC(self.hwnd, wDC)
            win32gui.DeleteObject(dataBitMap.GetHandle())

            # drop the alpha channel, or cv.matchTemplate() will throw an error like:
            #   error: (-215:Assertion failed) (depth == CV_8U || depth == CV_32F) && type == _templ.type() 
            #   && _img.dims() <= 2 in function 'cv::matchTemplate'
            img = img[...,:3]

            # make image C_CONTIGUOUS to avoid errors that look like:
            #   File ... in draw_rectangles
            #   TypeError: an integer is required (got type tuple)
            # see the discussion here:
            # https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/14866#issuecomment-580207109
            img = np.ascontiguousarray(img)

            return img

        # find the name of the window you're interested in.
        # once you have it, update window_capture()
        # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55547940/how-to-get-a-list-of-the-name-of-every-open-window
        @staticmethod
        def list_window_names():
            def winEnumHandler(hwnd, ctx):
                if win32gui.IsWindowVisible(hwnd):
                    print(hex(hwnd), win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd))
            win32gui.EnumWindows(winEnumHandler, None)

        # translate a pixel position on a screenshot image to a pixel position on the screen.
        # pos = (x, y)
        # WARNING: if you move the window being captured after execution is started, this will
        # return incorrect coordinates, because the window position is only calculated in
        #the __init__ constructor.
        def get_screen_position(self, pos):
            return (pos[0] + self.offset_x, pos[1] + self.offset_y)



    class Vision:

        # properties
        needle_img = None
        needle_w = 0
        needle_h = 0
        method = None

        # constructor
        def __init__(self, needle_img_path, method=cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED):
            # load the image we're trying to match
            # https://docs.opencv.org/4.2.0/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html
            self.needle_img = cv2.imread(needle_img_path, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

            # Save the dimensions of the needle image
            self.needle_w = self.needle_img.shape[1]
            self.needle_h = self.needle_img.shape[0]

            # There are 6 methods to choose from:
            # TM_CCOEFF, TM_CCOEFF_NORMED, TM_CCORR, TM_CCORR_NORMED, TM_SQDIFF, TM_SQDIFF_NORMED
            self.method = method

        def find(self, haystack_img, threshold=0.5, debug_mode=None):
            # run the OpenCV algorithm
            result = cv2.matchTemplate(haystack_img, self.needle_img, self.method)

            # Get the all the positions from the match result that exceed our threshold
            locations = np.where(result >= threshold)
            locations = list(zip(*locations[::-1]))
            #print(locations)

            # You'll notice a lot of overlapping rectangles get drawn. We can eliminate those redundant
            # locations by using groupRectangles().
            # First we need to create the list of [x, y, w, h] rectangles
            rectangles = []
            for loc in locations:
                rect = [int(loc[0]), int(loc[1]), self.needle_w, self.needle_h]
                # Add every box to the list twice in order to retain single (non-overlapping) boxes
                rectangles.append(rect)
                rectangles.append(rect)
            # Apply group rectangles.
            # The groupThreshold parameter should usually be 1. If you put it at 0 then no grouping is
            # done. If you put it at 2 then an object needs at least 3 overlapping rectangles to appear
            # in the result. I've set eps to 0.5, which is:
            # "Relative difference between sides of the rectangles to merge them into a group."
            rectangles, weights = cv2.groupRectangles(rectangles, groupThreshold=1, eps=0.5)
            #print(rectangles)

            points = []
            if len(rectangles):
                #print('Found needle.')

                #line_color = (0, 255, 0)
                #line_type = cv2.LINE_4
                #marker_color = (0, 255, 0)
                #marker_type = cv2.MARKER_CROSS

                

                # Loop over all the rectangles
                for (x, y, w, h) in rectangles:

                    # Determine the center position
                    center_x = x + int(w/2)
                    center_y = y + int(h/2)
                    # Save the points
                    points.append((center_x, center_y))

                    #if debug_mode == 'rectangles':
                        # Determine the box position
                        #top_left = (x, y)
                        #bottom_right = (x + w, y + h)
                        # Draw the box
                        #cv2.rectangle(haystack_img, top_left, bottom_right, color=line_color, 
                                    #lineType=line_type, thickness=2)
                    #elif debug_mode == 'points':
                        # Draw the center point
                        #cv.drawMarker(haystack_img, (center_x, center_y), 
                                    #color=marker_color, markerType=marker_type, 
                                    #markerSize=40, thickness=2)

            if debug_mode:
                cv2.imshow('Matches', haystack_img)
                #cv.waitKey()
                #cv.imwrite('result_click_point.jpg', haystack_img)

            return points

    pyautogui.PAUSE = 0.005

    Location1 = range(90, 289)
    Location2 = range(290, 400) # 394, 403f
    Location3 = range(450, 630)# 551, 565
    Location4 = range(640, 800) # 730, 695
    Location5 = range(801, 1000)
    empty = []

    # Change the working directory to the folder this script is in.
    # Doing this because I'll be putting the files from each video in their own folder on GitHub
    os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

    # initialize the WindowCapture class
    wincap = WindowCapture(None)
    # initialize the Vision class
    vision_limestone = Vision('Festivalnote.jpg')

    

    keys = []
    inputs = []

    loop_time = time()
    while 1:

        # get an updated image of the game
        screenshot = wincap.get_screenshot()

        #haystack_img = vision_limestone.apply_hsv_filter(screenshot)
        # display the processed image
        points = vision_limestone.find(screenshot, 0.5)#, 'rectangles')
        
        #cv.imshow('Matches', haystack_img)

        #length = len(keys)

        if points == empty:
            points = [(0, 0, 0)]
        
        if len(points) < 3:
            points.append((0, 0))
            points.append ((0, 0))

        first, sec, thd, *others = points
        #print(points)

        y_thresh = 175


        if first [0] in Location1 or sec[0] in Location1 or thd[0] in Location1:
            #print('d')
            pyautogui.keyDown("d")
            pyautogui.keyUp("d")
            #keys.append('d')
            #inputs.append('d')
            

        if first [0] in Location2 or sec[0] in Location2 or thd[0] in Location2:
            pyautogui.keyDown("f")
            pyautogui.keyUp("f")
            #print('f')
            #keys.append('f')
            #inputs.append("f")

        if first [0] in Location3 or sec[0] in Location3 or thd[0] in Location3:
            pyautogui.keyDown("j")
            pyautogui.keyUp("j")
            #print('j')
            #keys.append('j')
            #inputs.append('j')

        if first [0] in Location4 or sec[0] in Location4 or thd[0] in Location4:
            pyautogui.keyDown("k")
            pyautogui.keyUp("k")
            #print("k")
            #keys.append('k')
            #inputs.append('k')
        
        if first [0] in Location5 or sec[0] in Location5 or thd[0] in Location5:
            pyautogui.keyDown("l")
            pyautogui.keyUp("l")
            #print("l")
            #keys.append('l')
            #inputs.append('l')

        #if length == len(keys):
            #inputs.append(time() - loop_time)

        #print(inputs)
        # debug the loop rate
        print('FPS {}'.format(1 / (time() - loop_time)))
        loop_time = time()

        # press 'q' with the output window focused to exit.
        # waits 1 ms every loop to process key presses
        if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            break


    #with open("inputs.txt", "w") as output:
        #output.write(",".join(str(i) for i in inputs))
    print('Done.')
func()
```

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error and getting rid of useless code, I evntually figured out the problem was to do with them games refresh rate being slow and limiting the code not the code being slow.

Comment: this is just a comment. Could you be more specific?