opencv annotation tool loading image partially
the code that I am using to get the screenshot is this  :
import numpy as np
import win32gui, win32ui, win32con


class WindowCapture:

# properties
w = 0 
h = 0
hwnd = None
cropped_x = 0
cropped_y = 0
offset_x = 0
offset_y = 0

# constructor
def __init__(self, window_name):
    # find the handle for the window we want to capture
    self.hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, window_name)
    if not self.hwnd:
        raise Exception('Window not found: {}'.format(window_name))

    # get the window size
    window_rect = win32gui.GetWindowRect(self.hwnd)
    self.w = window_rect[2] - window_rect[0]
    self.h = window_rect[3] - window_rect[1]

    # account for the window border and titlebar and cut them off
    border_pixels = 10
    titlebar_pixels = 30
    self.w = self.w - (border_pixels * 2) 
    self.h = self.h - titlebar_pixels - border_pixels
    self.cropped_x = border_pixels
    self.cropped_y = titlebar_pixels

    # set the cropped coordinates offset so we can translate screenshot
    # images into actual screen positions
    self.offset_x =  window_rect[0] + self.cropped_x
    self.offset_y = window_rect[1] + self.cropped_y

def get_screenshot(self):

    # get the window image data
    wDC = win32gui.GetWindowDC(self.hwnd)
    dcObj = win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle(wDC)
    cDC = dcObj.CreateCompatibleDC()
    dataBitMap = win32ui.CreateBitmap()
    dataBitMap.CreateCompatibleBitmap(dcObj, self.w, self.h)
    cDC.SelectObject(dataBitMap)
    cDC.BitBlt((0, 0), (self.w, self.h), dcObj, (self.cropped_x, self.cropped_y), win32con.SRCCOPY)

    # convert the raw data into a format opencv can read
    dataBitMap.SaveBitmapFile(cDC, 'debug.bmp')
    signedIntsArray = dataBitMap.GetBitmapBits(True)
    img = np.fromstring(signedIntsArray, dtype='uint8')
    img.shape = (self.h, self.w, 4)

    # free resources
    dcObj.DeleteDC()
    cDC.DeleteDC()
    win32gui.ReleaseDC(self.hwnd, wDC)
    win32gui.DeleteObject(dataBitMap.GetHandle())

    # drop the alpha channel, or cv.matchTemplate() will throw an error like:
    #   error: (-215:Assertion failed) (depth == CV_8U || depth == CV_32F) && type == _templ.type() 
    #   && _img.dims() <= 2 in function 'cv::matchTemplate'
    img = img[...,:3]

    # make image C_CONTIGUOUS to avoid errors that look like:
    #   File ... in draw_rectangles
    #   TypeError: an integer is required (got type tuple)
    # see the discussion here:
    # https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/14866#issuecomment-580207109
    img = np.ascontiguousarray(img)

    return img

# find the name of the window you're interested in.
# once you have it, update window_capture()
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55547940/how-to-get-a-list-of-the-name-of-every-open-window
@staticmethod
def list_window_names():
    def winEnumHandler(hwnd, ctx):
        if win32gui.IsWindowVisible(hwnd):
            print(hex(hwnd), win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd))
    win32gui.EnumWindows(winEnumHandler, None)

# translate a pixel position on a screenshot image to a pixel position on the screen.
# pos = (x, y)
# WARNING: if you move the window being captured after execution is started, this will
# return incorrect coordinates, because the window position is only calculated in
# the __init__ constructor.
def get_screen_position(self, pos):
    return (pos[0] + self.offset_x, pos[1] + self.offset_y)

I came up to the same issue from the start of capturing the image but the solution was simply to "import pyautogui" to my main function file
now what I am trying to do is to teach the cascade classifier to identify the image pattern of the items, to do so i have to use the annotation program provided by opencv in this link opencv annotation program
the image I am trying to load is this

the returned image that I am getting for the annotation program is this

note: I am not the not the perfect coder so I am following this tutorial with some small adjustments to the code learn code by gaming

by adding the code responsible of the issue will make easier to develop a strategy/solution

there is no code really.. I am just running the .exe file that is provided from opencv

you will have to ask for help author(s) of this .exe fie. OR you may have to find source code for this file and debug it. But this program can be created in C/C++ instead of Python

here you can download source code for 3.4.15 (file .tar.gz) and inside you can find folder /apps/annotation/ with source code for this .exe but it is code in C/C++

I think this C/C++ code may have similar problem as in answer below. But maybe you should use smaller image to see full image in window. And later you would have to resize all other images also to the same size.

is there a way to include the "pyautogui" to the code? I believe this might actually solve the issue..

The annotation tool is still available even in the latest 4.x release. It has a command line option maxWindowHeight, the description of which says "images larger in height than this value will be scaled down". Did you try that?

imshow() shows images 1:1 but then system scaling is applied to the window.
call namedWindow() with WINDOW_NORMAL. That makes the window resizable and the contents will be rescaled accordingly.

let me clear out the misunderstanding here, I am not writing a code to capture any screenshot or or any thing, I am reading my already scaled screenshots using the cascade annotation tool provided by opencv, to be able to train the cascade classifier that I am making , the like here is used to show how the the classifier is trained https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/dc/d88/tutorial_traincascade.html

you don't have any code, you just use a premade program from the opencv sources? go into its source, patch it as I suggest, recompile. -- if you still disagree, present a [mre] and review [ask].

it seems OP uses precompiled application created in C/C++ - I think I found source code in .tar.gz file on page source code for 3.4.15 in folder /apps/annotation/ (after uncompressing)- but OP may have problem to fix it and compile it to .exe :) I suggested (in comment below question) to use smaller images which will fit in window. Maybe it will be some easy solution for this problem :)

I have other idea: on blog PyImageSearch I saw Capturing mouse click events with Python and OpenCV with program similar to annotation but in Python. But this code selects region and crops it - so it would need extra code to write annotation. And then OP could use your suggestion about WINDOW_NORMAL :)

I wouldn't recommend rewriting such tools from scratch. should be just fine git-cloning the 3.4 branch, where the haar cascade training stuff still exists, making it build, then modifying https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/3.4/apps/annotation/opencv_annotation.cpp#L119 -- of course, if anyone wanted to rewrite that thing in Python, it would be a lot more maintainable than it is now (removed, because nobody wanted to maintain it...)

@ChristophRackwitz Removed only in 5.x, right? Since I still see it in 4.x branch, and the exe is still shipped at least in the standard windows package as of 4.8 (don't have any more recent one here). Still, only some 300 LOC, should be quite easy to port it to Python if the language was the issue.

IDK about anything anymore. people said the traincascade stuff was removed and only available in 3.4 now. looks like it's still there in 4.x. and IDK about this annotation "tool" at all.
